# Enrolling an Android Go Device with Meraki

Tags: mdm, meraki

I am trying to get a lower end device (Lenovo M7 Gen 3) enrolled in Meraki but it is looping as per the video below.

https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/730298322/privacy

Essentially, click enrol device takes me in an infinite loop and doesn't actually enrol.

Any ideas would be appreciated? Or if Meraki flat out doesn't work with Android Go I can let go find another MDM. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Meraki products require a license, which also entitles you to support.

This is a case where you should open a Meraki support request about the specific setup. Meraki will be the most helpful and should be able to provide you a concrete answer.

I've attached the support phone numbers for your convenience.

[image]

Comment: I have tried, when I create a case in the portal it simply vanishes though

Comment: I've posted the Meraki support phone numbers for your convenience.